# why does my Mac App not show up in 'LaunchPad'?

Tags: macos, cocoa, info.plist

one of my apps ( http://bit.ly/1iKQZAO ) just doesn't shop up in Apple's "LaunchPad" (for me and customers). i've reset the LaunchPad database and tried to add it manually (drag app icon onto launchpad icon), but it still doesn't show up.

does anyone know reasons why LaunchPad might refuse to list some apps?

the app is properly signed and runs with "gatekeeper".

thanks

Comment: i found the reason (but no workaround), LaunchPad ignores all apps that have 'uninstall' in their name ... they probably want to ignore uninstallers...

Comment: What? Is that for reall @user1259710? Got a link to documentation?

Comment: of course it is real. how about just trying it? regarding documentation....you do know that 99% of macOS behaviour is undocumented?

Comment: Actually I did try it. I created a small swift app called `Uninstall.app` and it does indeed not show up in Launchpad. You seem to be right, I just find it surprising.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me...

I couldn't copy .app to Launchpad icon on Dock, or refresh Dock, or anything either.

But then I tried copying the .app off the .dmg file to my Desktop the dragging it over the launchpad icon on my dock.

The I opened Launchpad to find it there, I then dragged .app of Desktop into Applications folder and Launchpad link updated.

Really hope this works for you!!!

Comment: This worked for me too.  I have a bunch of [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/)-made “site-specific browser” apps living at `~/Application/SSBs/` that weren't showing up in LaunchPad.  Dragging them directly onto Launchpad added them.

Comment: This no longer seems to work in OSX 11.6.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to rebuild database via terminal? just the way bellow?

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db; killall Dock
```

Also, make sure that your app is in the app folder. be careful with extension: (case sensitive .app instead .App)

hope it helps.

Comment: yes that's what i've meant with 'i've reset the LaunchPad database'   the extension is correct.  the app is actually in a subfolder of the applications folder...but tests show it doesn't make a difference if it is directly in the app folder. thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found another unexpected requirement: Launchpad will only show an application if its `CFBundleVersion` entry in the `Info.plist` file is correctly set to a version.

My app accidentally left this field blank (but populated `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleGetInfoString`), and Launchpad wouldn't show this app.

Comment: not sure this is unexpected. a`CFBundleVersion` is not optional, its mandatory - check the documentation. if you don't have it, its a wonder you can even start your app.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting my Mac did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I created an application using this my answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407885/21590

The problem was that it would not show up in the Launchpad.  I was able to get it to show up by doing:

1. Create a DMG disk image using Disk Utility.  File menu -> New Image -> Blank image.
2. Make sure the DMG is mounted.
3. Copy your application over to the DMG.
4. Copy the application back into the Application folder.

After this process, the application showed up in the Launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

First you move the app away from the application folder. Then you again put back to the application folder. Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Use app [Launchpad manager](http://launchpadmanager.com/) app and press Regenereate button on the menu

Answer (score 0):

try removing dock .db
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db
then restart mac
then open application folder and rename the apps that arent showing or move them to trash and move them back again